# Casting to a derived class doesnt work on view page(aspx)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, casting

Hi Im stuck on a simple problem

Say I have a class

```cs
public Abstract Animal
```

And I have 2 derived classes

```
public Cat : Animal
{ 
    public int NumberOfLegs {get;set;}
}
```

So I passed this to my viewpage

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage((IEnumerable<Animal>)
```

In the aspx page
I can't do this(it won't even compile). It won't recognize the NumberOflegs member

```
foreach (item in Model)

    (Cat)item.NumberOfLegs
```

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a couple of paranthesis to have the cast evaluate before you access the member:

```cs
((Cat)item).NumberOfLegs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process only "cats" then you could filter the collection using Linq

```
foreach (item in Model.OfType<Cat>())
  item.NumberOfLegs
```